# Find the primitives of $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, 
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\underset{t\leq x}{\inf}(t^2-t+1),\;x\leq\frac12\\\underset{t\geqslant x}{\sup}(-t^2+t+1),x>\frac12\end{array}\right.$$
Say if $f(x)$ has any primitives on $\mathbb{R}$ and if it has, write the primitive. I have no idea how to approach this problem since I have no idea how to proceed with the $\inf$ and $\sup$ functions and what they really are.

Comment: Inf is basically minimum, and sup is basically maximum. However they are just "fixed" versions of these functions, in the sense that the set $(0, 1)$ has no minimum, since there is no $x \in (0, 1)$ such that $x < y$ for all $y \in (0, 1)$. In this case we say the set $(0, 1)$ does not have a minimum, but its _infimum_ is 0. Does this give you enough to work out what $f(x)$ is?

Comment: Have you tried with a few concrete $x$ to figure out, for example what $\inf\limits_{x\le 0}(t^2-t+1)$ is? Once you get the inf and sup rewritten to concrete expressions, you can start integrating.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Can I find the inf just by doing the graph of the inside function for $x \leq \frac 12$?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the $\sup$ as $-t+t+1=1$.

Comment: @Delta-u indeed it was, my apologies.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'll try this and update it as an answer in 15 mins

Comment: @HenningMakholm And then you could correct me if I do something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have these functions if $g(x) = x^2-x+1$ and $h(x)=-x^2+x+1$, both defined w.r.t $f(x)$.

Now, how do I really get the $inf$ and $sup$ in function of $x$?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As:
$$t^2-t+1=\left(t -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1-\frac{1}{4}$$
so if $t \leq x \leq 1/2$:
$$\left(t -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \leq \left(x -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
and:
$$\inf_{t \leq x} \left(t -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}=\left(x -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$$
you can do the same for the $\sup$ to show that if $x >1/2$:
$$\sup_{t \geq x} \left(-\left(t -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{5}{4}\right)=-\left(x -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{5}{4}$$
and then you can take the primitive for $x>1/2$ and for $x \leq 1/2$ and adjust the constants.

---

As pointed out by @HenningMakholm if $f$ as a jump at $x=1/2$ there is no continuous function $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: You're right so far. But will the "primitive" you get even be differentiable at $x=\frac12$?

Comment: No, but there is no contradiction as it seems that $f$ is not continuous at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It's not a "contradiction", but it does mean that the function you get is _not a primitive_. A function with a jump discontinuity can never be a derivative, so it doesn't have a primitive.

Comment: Ok I see your point :-)